# Error while creating publishing site using site template

Tags: 2016, publishing-site, site-template, site-creation

I have migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. 
I took a site template of a publishing site and while creating a site using the site template I get "Sorry something went wrong" error.

**Below is the error from hive logs:**

> Exception attempting to ApplyWebTemplate to SPWeb
>   https://hostname/site:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception
>   e, Boolean force)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionListInstances(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags,
>   Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb
>   webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags
>   activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition
>   featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid
>   featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version
>   version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope
>   featdefScope)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite
>   site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean
>   fIgnoreMissing)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken,
>   Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb(Byte[]&
>   userToken, Guid& tranLockerId, Int32 nZone, Guid databaseid, Guid
>   siteid, Guid webid, String sFeatures, Boolean fIgnoreMissing)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>   fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32&
>   plWebTemplateId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>   fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32&
>   plWebTemplateId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate
>   webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate
>   featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior
>   featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1&
>   featureDependencyErrors)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate,
>   Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior
>   featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1&
>   featureDependencyErrors)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb
>   Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav,
>   Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError,
>   SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior,
>   ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)

I tried taking the site template multiple times but still see the same error.

Anybody faced this issue? What is the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The message pointed that a feature is missed. Check in the original SharePoint 2010 if it has some customization (in farm, web scope) chack if is possible to have this feature installed in  SHarePoint 2016 or if you can uninstall the missed feature in sharepoint 2010 and then export it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to Msft, the site template feature isn't supported for sites that *have ever had* publishing features enabled. They claim "certain publishing features aren't supported" but don't elaborate on what or why. In general, the site template option is poorly engineered and often the error complains about features that aren't present in site settings, so can't be enabled or disabled.